# Searching for an efficient Client-Server-Networking method

Tags: sockets, networking, network-programming, client-server

I have a Server and a ton of Clients. (1,000 - 1,000,000)
I am new to networking.
I would like realize the System as follows:

1. Client registers to the Server. (through a normal Socket-Connection)
2. Connection is closed after registration.

Receiving a message:

4. Server sends a 'wake-up-packet' to the Client, which then connects (through the Socket-Connection) to the Server to retrieve the data that's waiting.
5. Connection gets closed after data-transfer is over.

Sending a message:
 1. Client connects by itself to send data.
 2. Connection gets closed after data-transfer is over.

In PHP, Server-Sent-Events do this job and I have not found an equivalent for Java, C++ or C# (the languages I have to chose from).

If you know technique that does what I described (or something similar) or, if you have a better (more resource-efficient) Client-Server-Model and maybe even an example of the implementation then please leave an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Simon

Comment: How will your server's wake-up-packet get through the client's firewall?  (It's not impossible, but you'd need to make use of UDP hole-punching techniques, which don't always work)

Comment: Also, how many clients are in a ton?  :)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I know that that might be a problem... And that's why I didn't pick a solution I found via Google. Should I maybe keep the connection open instead and forget about the efficiency?
I plan(ed) for at least 1000 clients at a time, but I hope for it to be able to be much more like a million if it works, like I described.

Comment: If you google "c10k problem" it should bring up a number of useful articles about approaches for supporting many clients on a server.  Read through those if you haven't already.

Comment: Why close the connection after registration? It's exactly what you need. Omit this step and the problem is solved.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: I have read about that already. I had hoped that there was something I had overseen or a protocol that I didn't know about.

Comment: @EJP: I wanted to have as much connected Clients as possible and my initial thought was: "Why don't close the inactive connections until they are needed again."